# Extract Data From wikipedia using Beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a wikipedia page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2014_AFL_season

What I need is to prepare a dictionary with Round as key and its corresponding data as its value.

Like:

```
myDict = {"Round 1": [["Date","Loser Team ", "Winner Team ","Stadium", "Crowd"],  ["Date","Loser Team ", "Winner Team ","Stadium", "Crowd"].......], "Round 2":[["Date","Loser Team ", "Winner Team ","Stadium", "Crowd"],  ["Date","Loser Team ", "Winner Team ","Stadium", "Crowd"].......]
```

So this dictionary will have all data stored.

Please help me to do this. I am using BS4 and urllib2 in Python.

I used the following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2



header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

def createLink():

    url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2014_AFL_season"

#     mainPage = urllib2.Request(url,headers=header)

    mainPage = urllib2.urlopen(url)

    mainPageSoup = BeautifulSoup(mainPage)

    for index in mainPageSoup.findAll("table"):
        print index

createLink()
```

Comment: Show us your BS code.

Comment: I was trying to figure out before really writing the code. I got confused and posted the question

Comment: My guess, maybe completely wrong, is you'll find more structure in the wiki code (i.e. go into "edit") that would be easier to parse.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it askes for code and doesn't show any effort.

Comment: I will give the code here, give me some time

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the fact that each table is preceded by a `H3` element with the round:

```
rounds = {}

for table in soup.select('h3 + table'):
    round_name = table.find_previous_sibling('h3').span.get_text().strip()
    if not round_name.lower().startswith('round'):
        break  # all rounds found
    entries = []
    for row in table.find_all('tr', style=False):
        cells = row.find_all('td')
        if len(cells) < 5:
            continue
        date = cells[0].get_text()
        loser = cells[1].a.get_text()
        winner = cells[3].a.get_text()
        venue = cells[4].a.get_text()
        crowd = cells[4].a.next_sibling.strip(' \n()')
        rounds[round_name] = [date, loser, winner, venue, crowd]
```

Comment: I used you suggestion but got this error:

    `round_name = table.previous_sibling('h3').get_text().strip()
TypeError: 'NavigableString' object is not callable`